# Keep Getting "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree"

Tags: git

I'm managing a site using the setup in this article: http://toroid.org/git-website-howto

It has been working great for several years but I recently moved the site to AWS and had to reconfigure the remote repo.  Here is my setup:

- Local repo setup using git init, then added all the files
- Remote repo setup using git --init bare
- Created post-receive file in the remote hooks folder, chmod +x to make it executable

The hook contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/destination/folder/for/checkout git checkout -f
```

Whenever I try running the hook (from the root of the bare remote repo):

```
./hooks/post-receive
```

I get

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

I have tried making the remote repo NOT bare, but that did not work.  I am on Ubuntu 14.04 using git 2.5.8

Any help or pointers appreciated!

Comment: Does the directory `/path/to/destination/folder/for/checkout` exist?  Git is OK with an empty directory, but not with a non-existent one.

Comment: Yes, the directory does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by treating the final destination as a repository (because it is, actually lol) So now the post-receive hook looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /final/destination/path
git checkout origin -f
```